# Generating sequence numbers in Java

Tags: java, random, sequence

I would like to generate sequence number from 01 to 10. But I only want the odd ones. For example,

01
03
05
07
09

I tried this way.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    String sequence = String.format("%02d", i);
    System.out.println(sequence); //this prints out from 01,02,03.... to 09.
```

So how should I change my code to omit the even ones in between?

Comment: Any reason you don't just use `i += 2` in the loop?

Comment: my bad, Brendan. I have edited it now.

Comment: ones are not even. and what you want could also be `if(i%2==1)` (the modulo operator)

Comment: @nl-x would be less efficient though

Comment: @Chandrew that's why I didn't put it as an answer. But it can't hurt Zip's mind to know this

Comment: And another think he could have dont is just change `i` on the second line into `++i`. (Again, perhaps less efficient, but nice to know)

Comment: Likewise, can't hurt to let him know :P

Comment: this would be a great chance to use the , operator : for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++, i++) ;)

Comment: @SimonMeyer what does that operator do, and is it only in java? BTW, anyone know if `++i++` works, and if `i++++` works? (I don't have a java machine)

Comment: i was just trolling around - almost noone uses that operator and i think thats good. But you can use it for variable declarations and in loop declarations to have both statements executed like: for(int i = 1, j = 10; i < 3; i++, j--)

Comment: Just a heads up for people reading these comments, "Unlike C and C++, the Java programming language has no comma operator."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want it formatted, only with odd numbers, this outputs:

01 03 05 07 09

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i+=2)
  System.out.println( String.format("%02d", i) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop changing the increment stage:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2)
    System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: haha.. I am so used to with the old for loop and forget that I can do this way. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No need to change the 10 to 8 @AnubianNoob

Answer (score 1):

You can just make the loop increment by 2 instead of by just 1!

Example with your code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i+=2) 
{
    String sequence = String.format("%02d", i);
    System.out.println(sequence);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use a loop

For loop

```
for(int i=1;i<=10;i+=2)
System.out.println(i);
```

While loop

```
int i=1;
while(i<=10){
System.out.println(i);
i+=2;
}
```

Do-While loop

```
int i=1;
do{
System.out.println(i);
i+=2}while(i<=10);
```

Comment: @nl-x : No they wont! after 9 i will become 11 and the loops will break!

Comment: You don't like spaces?

Comment: @Chandrew : what do you mean?